# Gitlab Deploy Token Use in CICD Fails for Submodule Update

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am running a CICD pipeline in Gitlab for deploying some stuff via python. As part of this, a submodule update must be done to pull the newest code from two private repos. The basic structure is as followings:

```
gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/B/project1.git <- Project with CICD
gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/C/project2.git <- Project it must pull code from during submodule update
gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/D/project3.git <- Project it must pull code from during submodule update
```

To allow for this I have created deploy tokens in both gitlab.com/MainOrg/Bar/Foo/project2.git and gitlab.com/MainOrg/Other/Foo/project3.git which have read access to the repositories. The main project repo for the CICD pipeline has the following .gitmodule:

```
[submodule "project2"]
    path = project2
    url = https://${C_READ_USERNAME}:${C_READ_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/C/project2.git
[submodule "project3"]
    path = project3
    url = https://${D_READ_USERNAME}:${D_READ_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/D/project3.git
```

(the variables have both been added under CICD settings for project 1 )and a .gitlab-ci.yml that looks like the following:

```
stages:
  - prod

prod_job:
  stage: prod
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3-venv
    - apt-get install -y python3-pip
    - git submodule init
    - git submodule update
    - python3 -m venv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - python3 code.py
```

This fails with the error:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.

However, if I try to clone one of the repos directly like this:

```
stages:
  - prod

prod_job:
  stage: prod
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y python3-venv
    - apt-get install -y python3-pip
    - git clone https://${C_READ_USERNAME}:${C_READ_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/MainOrg/A/C/project2.git
    - python3 -m venv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    - python3 code.py
```

It works without issue. I assume that the variables in the submodule are not getting swapped with their corresponding values, but I am unsure how to fix this, as based on the documentation it *should* work. Any thoughts?
Thanks